# Setup rails3 text_field for rocket_tag tag list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

This is the first time I've tried to add a tags field to a form so bear with me.

I'm using:

- rails 3.2.8
- Postgres 9.1
- rocket_tag 0.5.6
- squeel 1.0.9

I have installed the `rocket_tag` gem and run the various commands

```
rails generate rocket_tag:migration
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
```

to set everything up.

I've amended my Meeting model:

*Adding `:tags` and `:tag_list` to `attr_accessible`

*Adding `attr_taggable :tags`

*I've added a virtual attribute for displaying the tag list in the form field:

```
def tag_list
  self.tags.join(",")
end

def tag_list=(new_tags)
  self.tags = new_tags.split(/,[\s]*/).reject(&:empty?)
end
```

*I have added `f.text_field :tag_list` to my form view

This left me with my list page not working though. It said `Association named 'taggings' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`

```
User
  has_many :meetings
  has_many :meeting_dates, :through => :meetings

Meeting
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :meeting_dates

Meeting Dates
  belongs_to :meeting
```

In my list page I list meeting dates using:

```
 user_meeting_dates = @user.meeting_dates.includes(:meeting => :user)
```

To get past the taggings error I seem to need to have the following in my Meeting Dates model:

```
has_many :taggings, :through => :meeting
has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
```

Can someone explain why I need these here and whether there's a way to tidy this up any more, it doesn't seem like it's right.

Should it not be possible to do something like:

```
 user_meeting_dates = @user.meetings.meeting_dates
```

Thanks

Once I've got this working correctly I can move on to apply [Select2](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails/) to my [tags field](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#tags) but I need to get it working just from a plain text field first.